# Insert XML nodes into a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I want to get an XML data and insert each node value in a row of a table. For example I have:

```
<Tags> 
    <Tag>a</Tag> 
    <Tag>b</Tag> 
    <Tag>c</Tag>
</Tags>
```

and I want to insert a, b and c in a table named `Tags`. How should I do this?

I have this code so far but I don't know how to define `@I` in the xquery part. By the way is there any simpler way?

```
CREATE TABLE #T (tag nvarchar(100))

DECLARE @TagsXML xml
DECLARE @TagsCount int
DECLARE @I int = 0

SET @TagsXML = '<Tags><Tag>a</Tag><Tag>b</Tag><Tag>c</Tag></Tags>'
SET @TagsCount = (SELECT T.x.value('count(Tag)', 'nvarchar(100)') FROM @TagsXML.nodes('Tags') T(x))

WHILE @I < @TagsCount
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #T VALUES ((SELECT T.x.value('concat("Tag[", @I, "]")', 'nvarchar(100)') FROM @TagsXML.nodes('Tags') T(x)))
    SET @I = @I + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #T
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `WHILE` loops - **think in sets!**

You can do this easily in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO #T(tag)
    SELECT
        XTags.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)')
    FROM 
        @TagsXML.nodes('/Tags/Tag') AS XTbl(XTags)
```

The call to `.nodes()` gives you a list of the XML tags that match this XPath expression (as XML fragments) - here, you get a list of all `<tag>` elements. And from that list of XML fragments, I pick the only element's contents as `nvarchar(100)` and insert it into the table. Much more efficient and much better performing than a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) approach with a `WHILE` loop